# Nearby.Messages is not enabled for this app

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm having some trouble using the Nearby API. When I try to send a message after connecting to the API I get the following status message:

> Nearby.Messages is not enabled for this app: myApplicationId

I have followed the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-started) and I have the following in my Manifest:

```
<application>

    <!-- Testing Nearby -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.nearby.messages.API_KEY"
        android:value="AI………mykey…………s" />

</application>
```

In the Google Developers Console I have created a new project and enabled the **Nearby Messages API**. I have also added an Android client key in the Credentials section. I have copied the **API key** into the metadata (as shown above). I took the **SHA1** from my debug signing key along with my applicationId and added them into my **allowed applications** associated with the **API key**.

I have also tried removing all the allowed applications based on this message with the same result:
"Or if you leave this blank, requests will be accepted from any Android application."

In my build.gradle I have the following:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:7.8.0'
```

I've tried with the full play-services too (as per the documentation). I left it overnight too, in case the issue was the adding of the SHA1/applicationId combination took time.

Comment: Did you ask for user consent with: status.startResolutionForResult(...)?

Comment: No; that's looks like the answer! :) Thank you. Put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you ask for user consent with: status.startResolutionForResult(...)?

You can find an example of that in the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/pub-sub#pubsub_example)